# What is relationship between project.clj and dependent library jar files?

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I am using lein 2.0

If a main application

```
(defproject rexfer "1.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "Filters standard report from Patriot Properties' AssessPro."
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.4.0"]
                 [org.clojure/tools.cli "0.2.2"]
                 [org.clojure/data.csv "0.1.2"]
                 [rexfer-csv "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"]
                 [util "1.0.7-SNAPSHOT"]]

  :omit-source true
  :main rexfer.core)
```

depends on a library (util 1.07-SNAPSHOT)

```
(defproject util "1.0.7-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "A general purpose Clojure library"
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.4.0"]
                 [clojure-csv/clojure-csv "1.3.2"]
                 [org.clojure/data.csv "0.1.2"]]
  :aot [util.core]
  :omit-source true)
```

is the reference fetching a .jar file or a standalone .jar?

Another way to ask this question is should I be building standalone jars for libraries like

`util "1.0.7-SNAPSHOT"`

that require a main application to use them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should deploy the jar produced by `lein jar` rather than `lein uberjar`. You can also safely expect all reasonable libraries to be deployed in this way.

This is roughly because of the following:

1. correctly prepared jars contain metadata on their dependencies, so users will know to fetch the dependencies along with your jar;
2. it often happens that a project uses several libraries which share common dependencies -- it would be wasteful to have each shared dependency replicated in several jars;
3. the user may have good reason to override some of your dependency choices (which happens all the time, incidentally; replacing a transitive dependency with a different version or excluding a transitive dependency is common) -- with a regular jar they will be able to do so easily, while it would be a pain with an überjar.

Of course if the coordinates of some of your dependencies do happen to point at überjars, that's what's going to end up being pulled in by Leiningen. I've never come across a library misdeployed like that though.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to run lein uberjar then the answer to your second question would be yes. These jars need to be available on the class path for the main application to run. The job of `lein uberjar` is to include all the dependencies and dependencies of dependencies etc.

Comment: I think his question is: are the dependency jar files from Clojars and Maven (for example) uberjars or non-uberjars.

Comment: ohh, that makes more sense.